# PostgreSQL function to_timestamp(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I'm executing the query below and it gives me this error.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) > 0
FROM
    fight_events
WHERE
    "locationId" IN (
        SELECT
            "locationId"
        FROM
            users
        WHERE
            id = 31
    )
    AND to_timestamp("from") <= 1623253727754 AND 1623167327754 <= to_timestamp("to");
```

I want to compare the dates. The timestamps `1623253727754` and `1623167327754` come from the client, the "from" and "to" fields come from the DB.

Comment: `"from"` is already a timestamp. `to_timestamp` converts something that is not a timestamp to a `timestamp`, so passing the `"from"` column to it makes no sense. And why are you comparing a `timestamp` to an integer, not to a `timestamp` value?

Comment: The integers are unix timestamps. Ah, I got it, I messed up everything...so it's the integers that have to be converted to timestamps. So it should be like this `AND "from" <= to_timestamp(1623253727754) AND to_timestamp(1623167327754) <= "to"` Right?

Comment: Yes (but you need to divide the value by 1000). But why no compare them to a proper timestamp literal? e.g. `<= timestamp '2021-06-09 17:48:47'`

Comment: Yes, it's another option. In that case these integers should be converted to timestamp literals.